# Calculate a p-value in Python

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels, feature-selection, p-value

I used the `statsmodels.formula.api`  as below to calculate P-values. But apparently, this is not working in the new versions of the library. Do you know an alternative tool?

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
# ...
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(Y, x).fit()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: module 'statsmodels.formula.api' has no attribute 'OLS'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `statsmodels.api`, instead of `statsmodels.formula.api`.

Answer (score 0):

try changing
`regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(Y, x).fit()`
to
`regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog=Y, exog=x).fit()`